# How to run Exchange powershell Commands through windows command prompt?

Tags: exchange-server

I am trying to run Exchange PowerShell Commands through windows Command Prompt.
I searched for the same and found

powershell.exe -command Get-mailbox

which results into the following error

The term 'get-mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, scr
ipt file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
 included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:12
+ get-mailbox <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-mailbox:String) [], Command
   NotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I found one more way that is creating a .ps1 file.so I created a .ps1 file named A.ps1 having one System command(Copy that is running successfully) and one exchange command 
it again results into the same like above error.

**note**: I am running cmd as an elevated user only.
I don't know where i am going wrong.
I also found many other commands but each results into the same error (command not recognized as cmdlet..)

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated
 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The exchange commands don't work in a normal Powershell console, you need to first establish a [connection to your Exchange Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335083(v=exchg.160).aspx). The code example in the linked TechNet article will ask the user to input the credentials to connect to the exchange server. If you would like to "save" the credentials I would recommend to encrypt your credentials and don't save it in clear text in your script! For an example see this [two part Blog article](https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-1/) from PDQ.